# Display inside tag correctly - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the pagination links all work correctly, but the only problem is that inside the div `id="ajaxList"` displays again all the content of the page

[Form And table list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irnSb.jpg)

[All page content displayed within the id="ajaxList" after clicking the pagination link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4YXF.jpg)

Jquery

```
$(".page-link").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).attr("data-href");

   $( "body #ajaxList" ).load( url + "#ajaxList" );

})
```

Console alert:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

I tried in several ways to inform the parents sequence but it does not work, it only works if it displays directly in the `'body'` without specifying some `id` or `class`

```
$( "#ajaxList" )

$( "body #ajaxList" )

$( "body .col #ajaxList" )

$( "html body .col #ajaxList" )
```

I am using `jquery-3.2.1`

class.crud.php

```
public function paging($query,$records_per_page)
    {
        $starting_position=0;
        if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
        {
            $starting_position=($_GET["page_no"]-1)*$records_per_page;
        }
        $query2=$query." limit $starting_position,$records_per_page";
        return $query2;
    }

    public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
    {
        $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($total_no_of_records > 0)
        {
            ?><ul class="pagination"><?php
            $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);

            $current_page=1;

            if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
            {
                $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
            }
            if($current_page!=1)
            {
                $previous =$current_page-1;
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=1'>First</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a  href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Previous</a></li>";
            }
            for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($i==$current_page)
                {
                    echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;'>".$i."</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
                }
            }
            if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
            {
                $next=$current_page+1;
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."'>Next</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            ?></ul><?php
        }
    }
```

index.php

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="ajaxList">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th >#</th>
                  <th style="display:none">id</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Tel</th>
                  <th>City</th>
                  <th>Contry</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody >

                 <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM crud ORDER BY id DESC";       
                    $records_per_page=7;
                    $newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
                    $crud->dataview($newquery);
                 ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="7" align="center">
                        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                        <?php $crud->paginglink($query,$records_per_page); ?>
                        </nav>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>  
        </table>
```

Comment: Without the relevant code it's impossible to help. Images usually don't help anyone...

Comment: @Dekel Thanks, I added the code to my question

Comment: I really think you should rethink about this question. Remove everything that isn't relevant and ask only about the part you have problems with.

Comment: I made a question with just the part with which I have problem, and I had dowvotes for explaining little, now I think I explained a lot haha

Comment: I didn't see the other question, so I can't comment about the downvote, but currently there is too much code there and I really don't think that all of this code is relevant to the question.

Comment: @Dekel Please see if the question is better.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should remove as much as you can while still keeping the bug. For instance, do you really need all 5 columns in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a space after the target page URI, so instead of:

```
url + "#ajaxList"
```

use this:

```
url + " #ajaxList"
```

> If one or more space characters are included in the string, the
>   portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a
>   jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

As found in [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Also, once you remove the `.page_link` anchor, than you would have to bind click event once again. To avoid that, simply bind to body this way:

```
$("body").on("click", ".page-link", function() { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks, I already had trying it this way too, but after clicking on any number ajax loads the page correctly in the `id="ajaxList"` but this only happens in the first click, when I try to click another number again the buttons does not work and the url in the browser is `localhost/site/index.php#`, with`#`in the last character of the url

Comment: Yes!!! I'm really really happy to finally see this working. And thank you very much for your explanation. A million thanks